# Deleted layout resource still exists in R.java

Tags: android, android-layout, file-io

I have an issue where I delete something from my layout - Textview, Button, no matter..
And when I make another view and try and name it the same, I get an error saying that "Resource with that name already exists".

When I try and delete id manualy, from R.java, I cannot do it, ofcourse.

So I don't know how to really get rid of that resource.

Btw, It just occured to me, that I may have deleted the whole relative layout with some buttons inside. They don't longer appear in my xml file.
But could that be an eclipse bug?
Deleting layout with other objects inside it not really deleting everything ?

All in all, does anybody know how to permanently delete resources?

Comment: Try cleaning your project from project --> clean in eclipse.

Comment: No, it's not working. Already tried that :)

Comment: I am not sure about this but try deleting the gen folder , it should auto generate again.

Comment: THat's a tough call. It's  a big project, I worked on it for month. I dont wanna see it not auto generate from some reason. Knowing my luck, it can happen

Comment: You can always take a backup and try . :) Although this is not a solution.

Comment: One more thing is - you should not have any problems in any of the resources(layouts and all ) . It stops the regeneration of R.java .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your "gen" and "bin" folder, clean your project and run.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do more. Delete your `R.java` file or whole `gen` folder and `clean` the project again.